# How to implement 3rd order Polynomial Formula calculations in C on a 16bit MCU

Tags: c, data-manipulation, radix, polynomial-math

it is my first time posting but I'll start by apologizing in advance if this question has been asked before.

I have been struggling on how to implement a 3rd order polynomial formula in C because of either extremely small values or larger than 32bit results (on a 16bit MCU).
I use diffrent values but as an example I would like to compute for "Y" in formula:

```
Y = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d = 0.00000012*(1024^3) + 0.000034*(1024^2) + 0.056*(1024) + 789.10
```

I need to use a base32 to get a meaningful value for "a" = 515
If I multiply 1024^3 (10bit ADC) then I get a very large amount of 1,073,741,824

I tried splitting them up into "terms A, B, C, and D" but I am not sure how to merge them together because of different resolution of each term and limitation of my 16bit MCU:

```
u16_TermA = fnBase32(0.00000012) * AdcMax * AdcMax * AdcMax;

u16_TermB = fnBase24(0.000034) * AdcMax * AdcMax;

u16_TermC = fnBase16(0.056) * AdcMax;

u16_TermD = fnBase04(789.10);

u16_Y = u16_TermA + u16_TermB + u16_TermC + u16_TermD;

/* AdcMax is a variable 0-1024; u16_Y needs to be 16bit */
```

I'd appreciate any help on the matter and on how best to implement this style of computations in C.

Cheers and thanks in advance!

Comment: Ctrl_Shift_F, are the coefficients 0.00000012,  0.000034, 0.056, 789.10 always about that scale factor different (about 100x) from each other?

Comment: I just wrote down some random numbers but I use different values depending on the resulting curve equation that I need. But mostly my problem is in the 1st term section where the value of a is in the "nano" values and x^3 would be in the "mega" values. (a real world sample equation would be: y=-0.0000003986x^3 + 0.00065353x^2 -0.423867 + 123.606

Answer (score 4):

One step toward improvement:

```
ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d --> ((a*x + b)*x + c)*x + d
```

It is numerically more stable and tends to provide more accurate answers near the zeros of the function and less likely to overflow intermediate calculations.

---

2nd idea; consider scaling the co-efficents if they maintain their approximate relative values as given on the question.

```
N = 1024; // Some power of 2
aa = a*N*N*N
bb = b*N*N
cc = c*N

y = ((aa*x/N + bb)*x/N + cc)*x/N + d
```

where `/N` is done quickly with a shift.

With a judicious selection of `N` (maybe 2**14 for high precision avoid 32-bit overflow), then entire code might be satisfactorily done using only integer math.

As `aa*x/N` is just `a*x*N*N`, I think a scale of 2**16 works well.

---

Third idea:

In addition to scaling, often such cubic equations can be re-written as

```
// alpha is a power of 2
y = (x-root1)*(x-root2)*(x-root3)*scale/alpha
```

Rather than `a,b,c`, use the roots of the equation.  This is very satisfactory if the genesis of the equation was some sort of curve fitting.

Unfortunately, OP's equation [roots](https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/algebra/cubicequation.php?a=0.00000012&b=0.000034&c=0.056&d=789.10&action=solve) has a complex root pair.

```
x1 = -1885.50539
x2 = 801.08603 + i * 1686.95936
x3 = 801.08603 - i * 1686.95936
```

... in which case code could use

```
B = -(x1 + x2);
C = x1 * x2;
y = (x-x1)*(x*x + B*x + C)*scale/alpha
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion! I think idea 1 and 2 will work with my current conditions. But your idea 3 seems interesting since I am also going to do some curve fitting.. But honestly, I do not quite understand it so may I ask your help to please elaborate more on the concept behind this.

Comment: @Ctrl_Shift_F A good explanation is based on coding needs, something not yet specified.  What is the range and type of `x, y`.  How was `a, b, c` derived? How much error is tolerable in forming `y`?  "limitation of my 16bit MCU" is unclear.  Even a [Turing machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine) can implement all of C, so a 16-bit processor in itself is not any issue.

Comment: Note to self: https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/algebra/cubicequation.php?a=-0.0000003986&b=0.00065353&c=-0.423867&d=123.606&action=solve